# How can I get frame from DJI H.264 vedio?

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to using Opencv to deal with the vedio from the DJI Drones, however, what troubles me is that I do not konw how to get a frame from the vedio, what's more, how can I transfer it to Mat?
Is there any bolgs or any way can help me? thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996098/how-to-listen-to-different-udp-ports-on-the-same-address-within-the-same-process  follow the answer in this to setup and test ffmepg way of grab image using udp. once it is success. phase the same ffmepg input in the cv::videocapture parameters as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916903/how-to-process-vlc-udp-stream-over-opencv

Comment: Oops! I think you may mislead my question, what I want to know is a way to Using OpenCV on DJI Camera Data, so I want to get a frame and transfer it to Mat so that I can deal with. honestly, thank you for giving me advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted with dji-dev on Github, here are the [response](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/548)